# What language would you recommend to make a script to transfer YouTube favorites/playlists from one account to another?

Tags: youtube

My friend's birthday is coming up soon and she lost the passwords to two of her YouTube accounts and the emails associated with them, so I'd like to do this for her. I only have game programming experience in various langauges, but I think that I could learn to do this. Any language recommendations/tips/thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend python as a fantastic general-purpose scripting language which is fairly quick to pick up. You'll find it's more versatile for system-programming than something like php, which would be another option.

You might look here as a starting point:
http://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide/NonProgrammers

Besides, if you learn python, you can then learn django, which is incredibly awesome!